# how to view local variable/object content in xcode debugger

Tags: xcode

I have the following piece of code in xcode and would like to inspect the contents of "link" which is a local object "ReaderDocumentLink *link" declared in the for loop and I set breakpoint at the line
"result = [self annotationLinkTarget:link.dictionary];" as show below:

```
-(id)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    id result = nil; // Tap result object

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        if (_links.count > 0) // Process the single tap
        {
            CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self];

            for (ReaderDocumentLink *link in _links) // Enumerate links
            {
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(link.rect, point) == true) // Found it
                {
                    result = [self annotationLinkTarget:link.dictionary]; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I tried "po link" and it doesn't work. (it reports error as below:

error: 'link' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type to use it

error: 1 errors parsing expression

So what shall I do to print out the details in the "link" object? including the contents of link.dictionary as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode added the notion of a log breakpoint. That's what the OP is asking for. And he's come upon one of it's biggest stopping points: po has to be turned loose on a type that has a description method that does something. I don't use these a lot for this very reason: there are too many integral types still in the code that you want to inspect.

You could turn the item into an object inside the breakpoint, but that's a nuisance too, e.g. [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5] and then po that.

Link should work here. Maybe you are trying to do po on a line where it's out of scope?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Very insightful. I follow your advice and step into the breakpoint line. The "link.dictionary" become annotationDictionary inside the annotationLinkTarget. So I "po annotationDictionary", this time no error any more, but I only got the following information:(CGPDFDictionaryRef) $26 = 0x0000806b [no Objective-C description available]. I wonder if there is a way to print out the content of this annotationDictionary in the debugger console? thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is that your class? Provide an implementation of description and you should see it. Glad it helped, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Either `NSLog` each property of `ReaderDocumentLink`

Or ovveride the `description` mdthod in `ReaderDocumentLink` and use `NSLog(@"%@",link):`

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Rob as the fact that here it should work,.

But I've seen strange thing happen with 'po' especially with "dot syntax".
So if you were trying `po link.dictionary` and it failed
I would suggest doing `po [link dictionary];` With or without the ";" I don't think it make a difference.
(I don't know why sometime dot syntaxe work perfectly and other time it doesn't)

Also I've seen times if I made a typo in a "po" and received an error message, no matter what I would try to "po" after would failed, so add to hit continue (or kill the app I don't recall) and go to that break point again.

And of course make sure you are doing "po" while `link` is in scope.

If nothing work try closing Xcode, sometimes its the solution.